# Implementation Robotium in Android Maven Project

Tags: android, unit-testing, user-interface, maven, robotium

I created Android Maven Project with android-quickstart-archetype ( https://github.com/akquinet/android-archetypes/wiki/android-quickstart-archetype )

I need to use Robotium ( http://code.google.com/p/robotium/ ) GUI Unit testing library.

I added dependencies in pom.xml.

How can i implement this library in my project. Can anybody helps me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement Robotium in Android Maven project you need to:

1. Add dependency in pom.xml. Dependensy you can get here: http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/Maven
2. Use android-with-test archetype. https://github.com/akquinet/android-archetypes/wiki/android-with-test-archetype

Answer (score -1):

From the [link](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/Getting_Started):

> Getting started
>
> ...
>
> When you have created a new test
>   project you need to add the Robotium
>   jar to the build path. In Eclipse that
>   is done by right clicking on the test
>   project --> Properties --> Java Build
>   Path --> Add (external) Jar.

Basically, to get the library running in your project, you simply need to add the jar to the classpath.